Read value discrepancy between jupyter file and .py file
I am facing a very strange problem. I have an hdf5-file from which I am reading data:
with h5py.File(file, "r") as f:

    print(f['data']['foo'][()][0])


The value printed is not the same as in the hdf5 file. This code is part of a function.
Actually the file is a .mat-file which I open in matlab and check the values. When I write exactly the same code in a jupyter notebook the read values are the right ones.
The values I read are small, e10^-5, and the discrepancy in reading is about 10%. Maybe this can help to find the origin of the problem.
I wrote a completely new function, only with the part above and the value were the right ones. I can't understand why there is a difference in the reading of the values, especially because it is the same code and the same environment.
I hope you can give me some hints to find the problem.
Cheers,
Arch

Why don't we have some example output and data of how such discrepancy looks like!

what is [()] supposed to be?
